# Dynamo db write operations

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, throughput

Dynamo db allows only 25 requests per batch. Is there any way we can increase this in Java as I have to process 1000's of records per second? Any solution better than dividing it in batches and processing them?

Answer (score 2):

the 25 per BatchWriteItem is a hard dynamodb limit as documented here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html

There is nothing preventing you from doing multiple BatchWrites in parallel. The thing that is going to gate how much you can write is the write-provisioned-throughput on the table.

Answer (score 0):

BatchWrites in DynamoDB were introduce to reduce the number of round trips required to perform multiple write operations for languages that do not provide opportunities for parallel threads to perform the work such as PHP.

While you will still get better performance because of the reduced round trips by using the batch API, there is still the possibility that individual writes can fail and your code will need to look for those.  A robust way to perform massively parallel writes using Java would be to use the [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) class.  This provides a simple mechanism to use multiple threads to perform the inserts.  However, just as individual items within a batch can fail, you will want to track the Future objects to ensure the writes are performed successfully.

Another way to improve throughput is to run your code on EC2.  If you are calling DynamoDB from your laptop or a datacenter outside of AWS the round trip time will take longer and the requests will be slightly slower.

The bottom line is to use standard Java multi-threading techniques to get the performance you want.  However, past a certain point you may need to fan out and use additional hardware to drive even higher write OPS.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you've got a large stream of real-time data that needs to end up in AWS, Kinesis Streams are probably the way to go. Particularly with [AWS Kinesis Firehose](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/firehose/), you can pipe your data to S3 at massive scale with no administrative overhead. You can then use DataPipeline to move it to Dynamo.